# How to add .get(position) in alert dialog box

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Realtime database and I want to get the position of the selected recycler view item and delete it, the only problem is in this part " String id = list.get(position).getId();" I can't seem to get the position of my selected item.

The error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'position'".

My dialog code:

```
    private void showDialog() {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(upcoming.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure ypu want to delete this item?");

    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String id = list.get(position).getId();
    Query queryRef = database.child("Reminder").orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);

            queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
                    snapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared your `onClick` as:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
```

If we look at [`DialogInterface.OnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener), we see that `which` is documented at:

> `which`   `int`: the button that was clicked (ex. `DialogInterface#BUTTON_POSITIVE`) or **the position of the item clicked**.

So the position of the item that was clicked is available in the `which` parameter, meaning you can use it with:

```
String id = list.get(which).getId();
```